# Laravel 4 - Eloquent: Is it possible to query all relations before accessing them?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to cache a DB query(and its relations),  but after experimenting with Eloquent ORM I realized that the relations are only queried when they're being accessed - which is, in my case, within the views.
  The problem is that the controller contains the whole caching process, and since the relations are accessed with the views; these relations are **never** cached.

So I've been looking for a way to pre-query every relation within the controller, the obvious solution was to access each relation manually within the controller, but it doesn't seem like an optimal solution.

**TL;DR**: Is there a way to query all(**or a subset of**) Eloquent relations before actually accessing them?

Comment: Are you looking for [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)? I think Eager/Lazy loading is optimal enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into eager loading.

```
class Bar extends Eloquent
{
    public function foos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Foo');
    }
}

$bars = Bar::with('foos')->get();
```

$bars now contains all Bars with all Foos preloaded in 2 SQL queries.